# Gauge animation in CSS

Tags: css, react.js, animation

Not sure how to show this here, but the stripes of the gauges shown below move from left to right:

[image]

The gauges represent a pokémon's base stats (here, Bulbasaur). The length of each gauge is determined as a % of the max value (65 in this particular case).

```css
/*-------------------------------
        Stat gauge animation
-------------------------------*/

.stat-gauge-bg {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #A1CD9B, #A1CD9B 5px, #91C58A 5px, #91C58A 10px);
  background-size: 1rem 1rem;
}

.stat-gauge-animation {
  -webkit-animation: 1s linear 0s infinite stat-gauge-stripes;
  animation: 1s linear infinite stat-gauge-stripes;
}

@-webkit-keyframes stat-gauge-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 1rem 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@keyframes stat-gauge-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 1rem 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

HTML (React):

```
export default function Gauge({ max, stat }: { max: number, stat: number }) {
  return (
    // static gray background
    <div className='h-[17px] w-[80%] bg-gray-300 rounded-md'>
      <div
        // set width as percent of stat with highest value
        style={{ width: `${(stat / max) * 100}%` }}
        // leading-[1.1rem] is to center text inside the div
        className={`
        leading-[1.1rem]
          h-[17px]
          rounded-md
          text-right
          text-white
          stat-gauge-bg
          stat-gauge-animation
          `}
      >
        <span className='mr-1'>{stat}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```